# How to make a div popup after 10 seconds or so (using javascript or php)?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make a div popup in the center of the page after 10 seconds after the page loads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this with Javascript's [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function.

The second argument is how long Javascript will wait (in milliseconds) until calling the first argument.

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block';
    }, 10000);
}
```

Assuming your DIV has `display: none;` to start and an ID of 'mydiv',  the above should work.